# Less verbose dynamic +=?

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
sObject.Custom_Field__c += myNumericVar;
```

But I'm using dynamic SOQL, so I can't hard-code the name of the fields.  The following code works, but it's really verbose and hard to read.  Is there a cleaner, easier-to-read way to do it?

```
sObject.put (fieldName, (Decimal) sObject.get(fieldName) + myNumericVar);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you must be requiring TYPE cast in above code i.e.

```
sObject.put (fieldName, ((Decimal)sObject.get(fieldName)) + myNumericVar);
```

The above code is good if you are using it in loop, as it saves script lines, all the above operation is done in 1 script line only. To make it more developer friendly and readable, one can change it to:

```
Decimal fldVal = (Decimal)sObject.get(fieldName);         
// Doing addition to save one script line 
sObject.put (fieldName, fldVal + myNumericVar);
```

Comment: Good catch w/ the Type casting; I accidentally deleted it when simplifying my code!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so.

Dynamic APEX has it's limitations around how it encapsulates the ORM.

Comment: Someone stole your user ??  That's not how you regulary answer Jordan

Comment: I honestly don't think it's possible! He was asking if there was a way to accomplish the same task in the fewer operations, and _I don't believe there is_. What more is there to say? How else can you dynamically assign a field-value on an sObject (even if it's guaranteed to be numeric), APEX is really strongly typed like that. Sure dynamic SOQL gives you some sense of a generic assignment but more for building dynamic assignments not letting the compiler interpret your typing.