# update a records using generic fields

Tags: apex

I need to update some fields in an object from apex.
The number of fields is not constant i.e. in some instances there might be 3 fields to be updated in some cases there could be 10.

I have these field names in a list of Strings that is generated dynamically.

Is there a way we could say

```
 contact.lstfieldname[0] = 'update value';
```

The above wouldn't work, is there a way we would mimic it?

Comment: Great question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the **get** and **put** methods on your object for this type of access. You can review the methods on the [SObject](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) base class (every standard and custom object supports these methods). Enjoy!

```
Contact contact = new Contact();
Map<String, Object> fieldValueMap = new Map<String, Object>();
fieldValueMap.put('Birthdate', System.today());
fieldValueMap.put('Description', 'Some descriptipon');
fieldValueMap.put('Title', 'Some title');
fieldValueMap.put('FirstName', 'Andrew');
fieldValueMap.put('LastName', 'Fawcett');
fieldValueMap.put('MyCustomField__c', 'My Custom Field Value');
for(String fieldName : fieldValueMap.keySet())
    contact.put(fieldName, fieldValueMap.get(fieldName));
insert contact;
```

Comment: Thanks for this reference to sObject base class, the get() method is useful for dynamically retrieving a field value when the Field name is delivered by something like a Custom Setting. http://sforce.co/1w44uSG

Answer (score 15):

2 loops: outer on your contacts, inner on your list of field names. And dynamic apex with get() and put(), like in this question: [Less verbose dynamic +=?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4036/less-verbose-dynamic)

```
List<String> fields = new List<String>{'FirstName', 'LastName', 'Email'};
List<Contact> contacts = [SELECT Id FROM Contact LIMIT 5];

for(Contact c : contacts){
    for(String fieldName : fields){
        c.put(fieldName, 'example@example.com'); // your constant here
    }
}
```

Having this sample you can experiment further: `Map<String, String> valuesToApply = new Map<String, String>{'FirstName' => 'John', 'LastName' => 'Doe'};`

Comment: exactly what i wanted.. You are god

Answer (score 3):

Following is the snippet code .I assume we have list of contacts to update and lst string to consider .

```
for(contact con:lstcontoUpdate){

for(String str:FieldstoConsider){

  con.put(str,'update value');

  }
}
```